# Find the nearest array index for accurate computation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation in Javascript that I am getting result from 2 endpoint with similar provider. I need to compute for "Price/Earnings Ratio" from finance API but the API does not provide the functionality to retrieve the value but there would be a workaround.

The computation of Price/Earnings Ratio for a particular year would be:
Last Stock Price of Mentioned Date / Date Earnings Per Share

now the problem would be if I got:

```
let as-of-date = "2019-12-31";
let as-of-date-eps = 2.00;
let ratio-as-of-date = as-of-date-eps/?
```

But the results of array of getting the nearest stock price for mentioned date would be.

```
let stock-price-history = [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-26",
            "open": 8.3,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.21,
            "volume": 162800
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-27",
            "open": 8.48,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8,
            "last": 8.19,
            "volume": 113000
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-01-02",
            "open": 8.45,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.4,
            "volume": 100000
        },
]
```

There would be no "2019-12-31" but I want to get the index of stock-price-history with date inside before 2019-12-31. so it's the second index or **stock-price-history[1].last** to complete the accurate computation. hence the expected Price/Earnings Ratio that I want would be **4.095**

The question would be how can I code to make sure that I got the second result.

Comment: Your question contains a lot of irrelevant details. If you want to compare dates, there are many libraries you can use and a lot of resources to read from (for example, moment.js)

Comment: Give two examples with input and the expected output. explanation is not clear.

Comment: It's kind of complicated. I can't edit my post. anyone can help how to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keep it simple:

- Calculate the difference between each date of each item and the chosen date
- save these indexes and differences/offsets into an array
- sort this by the offsets
- take the first (zero) index of this sorted array (and the first, zero index of that) as the minIndex
- use this to retrieve the item from your `stockPriceHistory` array

NOTE: the minimum offset is actually "2020-01-02" - "2019-12-31" = 2 days offset, whereas "2020-12-27" - "2019-12-31" = -4 days offset. I assume your logic is, don't include any days that are ahead of your chosen date?

```js
const chosenDate = new Date("2019-12-31");
const stockPriceHistory = [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-26",
            "open": 8.3,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.21,
            "volume": 162800
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-27",
            "open": 8.48,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8,
            "last": 8.19,
            "volume": 113000
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-01-02",
            "open": 8.45,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.4,
            "volume": 100000
        },
];

const dateOffsetsByIndex = stockPriceHistory.map((item, index) => {
  const currDate = new Date(item.date);
  const offset = (currDate - chosenDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); //days
  return [index, offset];
})
  //sort to sort by absolute offset:
  //.sort((a,b) => Math.abs(a[1]) - Math.abs(b[1]));
  //sort to sort by offset, but rank dates ahead of chosen as the "worst":
  .sort((a,b) => {
    if (a[1] > 0 && b[1] < 0){
      return 1;
    }
    if (a[1] < 0 && b[1] > 0){
      return -1;
    }
    return Math.abs(a[1]) - Math.abs(b[1])
  });

//console.log(dateOffsetsByIndex);

const minIndex = dateOffsetsByIndex[0][0];

console.log(stockPriceHistory[minIndex]);
```

You could also do this cleaner with reduce:

```js
const chosenDate = new Date("2019-12-31");
const stockPriceHistory = [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-26",
            "open": 8.3,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.21,
            "volume": 162800
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-27",
            "open": 8.48,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8,
            "last": 8.19,
            "volume": 113000
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-01-02",
            "open": 8.45,
            "high": 8.48,
            "low": 8.2,
            "last": 8.4,
            "volume": 100000
        },
];

const minOffset = stockPriceHistory.reduce((agg, item) => {
  const currDate = new Date(item.date);
  const offset = (currDate - chosenDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); //days
  if (!agg.offset) return  {...item, offset};
  if (agg.offset > 0 && offset < agg.offset) return {...item, offset}; 
  if (agg.offset < 0 && (offset > agg.offset && offset <=0)) return {...item, offset};
  return agg;
}, {});

console.log(minOffset);
```

Comment: After trying this out. I got it and modify my original code

Comment: Great, good to hear my answer helped solve the issue.